# On a Live Agent Pre Chat form, how can I make a field mandatory?

Tags: liveagent, required-field, pre-chat

I have a pre-chat page and it's working fine. I just need to make (say) the name field a required one. HTML 5 states you can use a "required" attribute on the `<input type="text" ... >`
But Salesforce won't let me save that.

Is it really down to JavaScript to validate the form?

**Update to show code as is**

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"
    standardStyleSheets="false" >
....
....
<input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:ContactName' id='ContactName' placeholder='Contact name' required='true' />
....
....
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" id='prechat_submit'/>
```

I'm wondering if there's something in there that shouldn't be - or formatting could be interfering, but I can't see how it would.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use javascript to ensure field requirements. This is a simple HTML attribute you can add to each field element. Add the following attribute to each field that needs to be required:

required="true"

First name:

```
<input required="true" type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:User_FirstName' id='customField1' /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `docType="html-5.0"` in the prechat vf page header. I used in the following way and it is working for me. Hope it will help.

```
    <apex:page showHeader="false" docType="html-5.0">
    ......
    ......
    <input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:FirstNameDetail' required='true' onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('prechat_field').value=this.value;" />
```

Screen

[image]

Comment: I've formatted my code (see amended question) to match yours - but same result.

Comment: If possible can you please post your entire pre-chat page code? Also what browser and version are you testing?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Live Agent. You need to validate using JavaScript as you would with any other page. Do not use the approach above as is not reliable on old browsers or for more advanced validations.